# How to specify which hidden files should remain hidden and choose which files are to be seen?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, hidden-files

For example, I have two folders .history and .trash

they both are from the same "tribe" but I never need to use the .history folder so it is useless to keep it in the explorer while .trash is useful to me and I need to view it regularly. 
I want to hide .history even when "show hidden items" is checked on or view .trash when "show hidden items" is checked off.

can it be done?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do exactly what you want. You can "show" a hidden folder without removing the dot in front. You have to create a symbolic link.

1. Open a terminal
2. Go to the folder containing the `.trash` hidden folder.
3. type `ln -s .trash Trash`

Now you have a symbolic link to `.trash` that shows even when hidden files are not shown.

Comment: Best to use full pathnames in your `ln` command. ie: `ln -s /path_to/.trash /home/username/Desktop/Trash` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `.hidden` in your home directory. Enter **folder names** or **filenames** in this file. Those will become/remain hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Files and folders that begin with `.` are hidden by default.

In order to "unhide" these files you will need to remove the `.` from the file name. Please note that this *changes the file name*, so if the file is called by some application, you may break things by changing the file name.

If you remove the `.` from `.trash` and `.history`, it can break applications that use them.  More likely, applications will just recreate the path.

As far as I know there is not any third category of properties for hidden files.  Either the file has a preceding `.` and it is hidden, or it doesn't and is not hidden.

Answer (score -1):

The files or directories with `.` before its name is hidden. To make it hidden/unhidden simply add/remove respectively.
In your case:

- Rename `.history` to `history`
- Rename `.trash` to `trash`

Both will be no more hidden.

#### WARNING

This may cause breaks that may be simple or even complicated depended on the applications using it.
**Do this with caution !!!**

Hope this helps.